# How to plot data vertically with labels

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a worksheet that looks like this:

[image]

What I need to do is to make a point chart where the Names are the vertical axis and the Dates are the horizontal axis. The points should have different colors base don the Label. When I tried to make this chart all axes are wrong and changing the Data Series breaks it even more. How would I make this chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `A1:C8` and that by "point chart" you mean a scatter chart

1) Insert a Scatter Chart (it will not look right -- that's OK

2) Right Click on the chart and select "Select Data Source"

3) Click on Add

[image]

4) use the following settings in the Edit Series Window:

[image]

5) Click "OK"

6) In the Select Data Source Window, uncheck all series except the one called "Label"

[image]

Your chart should now look like this:

[image]